# vqmod doesn't make changes in frontend files in opencart Version 2.0.0.0

Tags: opencart2.x, vqmod, opencart-module

hi friends i am working on open cart Version 2.0.0.0 to build an e-commerce site. i had downloaded some vqmod modules and integrate it in my localhost and its work fine.
if i uploaded the same files in my live site. the vqmod changes for frond end file are not working. i have tested with my own vqmod files to its to works for admin files and doesn't for front end files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><modification>
<id>test content</id>
<version>1.0.3</version>
<vqmver>2.2.1</vqmver>
<author>test</author>
<decription><![CDATA[
    /*
        This file is part test content
    */
    ]]>
</decription>

<file name="catelog/view/template/common/menu.tpl" error="log">
    <operation error="log">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            <li><a href="<?php echo $information; ?>"><?php echo $text_information; ?></a></li>
            ]]>
        </search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
            <li><a href="<?php echo 'jinna'; ?>"><?php echo "jinna"; ?></a></li>
            ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file></modification>
```

and this doesn't

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><modification>
<id>test content</id>
<version>1.0.3</version>
<vqmver>2.2.1</vqmver>
<author>test</author>
<decription><![CDATA[
    /*
        This file is part test content

    */
    ]]>
</decription>

<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl" error="log">
    <operation error="log">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            </header>
            ]]>
        </search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
            <li><a href="<?php echo 'jinna'; ?>"><?php echo "jinna"; ?></a></li>
            ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file></modification>
```

Comment: Have you checked for error log? Located at `vqmod/logs` folder

Comment: i found no logs folder inside vqmod. i have xml folder alone inside vqmod.
modified files are stored under "root/system/modification/catelog"

Comment: which version of vqmod, you are using ?

Comment: i dont know  "zed Blackbeard". all stuffs are working great in localhost.

Comment: open `vqmod/vqmod.php` file. Check line on 7 or around.

Comment: Add modification close tag. `</modification>`

Comment: i have no files and folders inside vqmod except "xml".

Comment: i missed </modification> tag in my question but the actual code have it..

Comment: Have you checked the vqmod version on server ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in comment that

[image]

it means, Vqmod is not installed on server.

**[Install vqmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart)**

To check vqmod is installed on your server or not. Follow the url

```
http://your-domain/vqmod/install/
```

Also give the 0777 permission to following folder and files.

1. `vqmod/vqcache` folder
2. `vqmod/mods.cache` file

Comment: i does't missed. it was omitted by the stackoveflow editor when it comes in new line.

Comment: its all working in my local machine's localhost. if i click modification inside admin panel its modified all the files in localhost.  if i do the same in live site admin panel, its only change the modification files which wanted to reflect in admin panel...

Comment: Now what is issue coming .. ?

Comment: have you gave 0777 permission to `vqmod/vqcache` folder and `vqmod/mods.cache` file on live server.

Comment: the header.tpl file doen't change with the text i mentioned, after </header> tag. sorry  zed Blackbeard. i have no such files inside vqmod folder..

Comment: i had removed this <vqmver>2.2.1</vqmver> and it raised error when i clicked modification refresh button under admin panel

Comment: Have you checked vqmod is installed or not properly and also show me the vqmod version . File version is depend upon the vqmod version. If the vqmod version is greater that this. So it will not run.